# FreeBSD XEN kernel not booting in XenServer 6.2

Tags: xen, freebsd, kernel, xenserver, paravirtualization

I have a XenServer 6.2 host, and I am trying to get a FreeBSD-9.1-i386 guest to run in PV mode.

The installation of the guest is fine, but after a reboot with the new kernel the system does not boot.

```
make buildkernel KERNCONF=XEN
make installkernel KERNCONF=XEN
reboot
```

This is all I see on boot:

```
FreeBSD/x86 bootstrap loader, Revision 1.1
(root@obrian.cse.buffalo.edu, Tue Dec  4 06:18:06 UTC 2012)
Loading /boot/defaults/loader.conf
/boot/kernel/kernel text=0x43bc20 _
```

I have found others with the same problem, but no responses to the bug submissions. I am not fully sure this is a bug, possibly me just missing something with the configuration. I appreciate any and all help/advise.

Comment: After searching for a while, I have found many others with the same issue but no real solutions offered. The XENHVM kernel boots fine, but only uses the block device and network PV drivers.